# Google chrome extension help : change the background-color of the clicked tag

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing this extension for Google chrome and basically what it does is when the extension is activated user can highlight the currently displaying web content of a web page(like when we highlight a PDF). (There are existing extensions, this is for my learning purpose).

And i'm new to  extension development and have less knowledge about the required technical  stuff.

As a start i made this simple extension which change the background color of the currently displaying web page when the extension icon is clicked.

code sample of .js file :

```
function clickss(e) {
   chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{code:"document.body.style.backgroundColor='yellow'"});
   window.close();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      clickss();
});
```

this will change the body background color instantly. So how can i make/modify this to only change the color of a tag (div , p , h) when user click on the particular tag(when user click on a web page only the tag related to that point of click, should change its background color).

As i'm new to this i highly appreciate kind answers.

Comment: I've made an article of doing this.It's in [here](http://bufferedstream.blogspot.com/2013/07/create-chrome-extenstion-to-highlight.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get the tags and attach a click event listener for each one.

You can use `getElementsByTagName()`

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for(var d in divs) {
   divs[d].addEventListener('click', clickss);
}

function clickss(e) {
   this.style.backgroudColor = "yellow";
}
```

Comment: so if i use this code it will again change the background color of the whole body. So how can i only change the color of a particular tag which the user clicks.

Comment: @Vidudaya, you can use `this` keyword to handle actual element.